# abort() function is not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to use the abort function but it is not working. Here is the code i am using. I am currently run this code on Laravel 5.2

```
Route::get('/test',function(){
abort(403);
});
```

It generates the following error

> HttpException in Application.php line 905:

I wanted to ask this function is still available or what i am doing wrong.

Comment: why you are using 403 code ??

Comment: I am just testing this method with 403 and 404 but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected behavior to show exception screen for `abort` calls from **~4.x**: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/912

use `response` with status code:

```
Route::get('/test',function(){
  return response(null, 403);
});
```

with `abort`:
[image: abort]

with `response(null, 403)`:
[image: response]

Comment: thanks the second suggestion work, but i don't wanted to disable debug mode for now.

Comment: @habib to be hones I never use abort call. I use response helper. it's more predictable

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this method `abort(403);` your users must have a roles.
see this example .
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-entrust-to-restrict-access-by-role-throwing-a-httpexception

Comment: see comments there: `Problem solved. Apparently it was simply missing a view for the error 404. After having added a resources/views/errors/403.blade.php page it will just call that page. My laravel only came with a 503.blade.php error page by default.`  so it's not about roles :D

Answer (score 2):

Use the response() helper method instead of abort(). Syntax as below:

```
return response("User can't perform this action.", 403);
```